# Поменять цвет png иконки в drawable

Tags: android, color, android-drawable

В `drawable` есть исонка в `png` формате. Черная, с прозрачным фоном. Как поменять ее цвет програмно, чтобы не приходилось добавлятьв `drawable` эту же иконку только серого цвета, белого цвета и т.п.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так:

```
public static Drawable tintIcon(Context context, @NotNull Drawable icon, int color) {
        icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon).mutate();
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(icon, ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, color));
        DrawableCompat.setTintMode(icon, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        return icon;
}
```

`color` - это либо один цвет, либо [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html).

Для API>=21 достаточно в разметке указывать соответствующие атрибуты `tint`.

Comment: Стоит, наверное, отметить, что `DrawableCompat` - класс из библиотеки поддержки *support.v4*, а методы `setTint()` и аналогичные для тинтинга были добавлены [только с версии 22.1.0](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: @pavlofff замечания верные, хотя без support'а мало кто пишет, а 22.1 вышла больше года назад, студия грязью закидает, что мол не обновился до сих пор...